# How to use tryCatch without global variables or superassignment

Tags: r, environment-variables, global-variables, cran, scoping

I am writing an R package with a `tryCatch()` loop of the following form, in which I first try to fit a model using an error-prone method but then use a safer method if the first fails:

```
# this function adds 2 to x
safe_function = function(x) {

  tryCatch( {
    # try to add 2 to x in a stupid way that breaks
    new.value = x + "2"

  }, error = function(err) {
           message("Initial attempt failed. Trying another method.")
           # needs to be superassignment because inside fn
           assign( x = "new.value",
                  value = x + 2,
                  envir=globalenv() )
         } )

  return(new.value)
}

safe_function(2)
```

This example works as intended. However, the use of `assign` triggers a note when checking the package for CRAN-readiness:

`Found the following assignments to the global environment`

A similar problem happens if I replace `assign` with `<<-`. What can I do?

Comment: Can't you do `new.value <- tryCatch( { x + "2" }, error = function(err) x+2 )` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are trying to use the global scope here. You can just return the value from the `try/catch`.

```
safe_function = function(x) {

  new.value <-   tryCatch( {
    # try to add 2 to x in a stupid way that breaks
    x + "2"
  }, error = function(err) {
    message("Initial attempt failed. Trying another method.")
    x + 2
  } )

  return(new.value)
}
```

Comment: But how would you go about when tryCatch isn't embedded into a function like in `safe_function` here? How would you make the variables defined within `tryCatch` accessible to the outer environment?

Comment: @MJimitater `tryCatch` will return a value whether or not it's called inside another function so I'm not sure what you are asking. Perhaps you can open your own new question if you have a different scenario.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, all is settled now - I was subject to the following quote by Norm Matloff: "Finding your bug is a process of confirming the many things that you believe are true — until you find one which is not true."